# Joining Bones on Intersection

Tags: armature

I'm making an armature in my project, and somewhere down the line I made a mistake. 4 bones making an intersection are not properly connected to each other. I can tell this because when trying to move the bones, they each go their independent way. Whilst the properly connected bones (like the forearm connected to the main arm, the shin connected to the thigh) move fine.

My question is how to connect all these bones together. I looked at the option of flipping one of the bones around and connecting all the bones to the tail. This option does not work for me because flipping the bone means that the other side of the bone will be disconnected, but I want both sides of the bone to be connected.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Picture of the 4 bones making an intersection]